# Is it possible to get a FlutterView from BroadcastReceiver/Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, flutter, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to build a Flutter app that does the following:

1) Run an alarm manager every minute (even when app is in background/closed).

2) When the alarm manager's onReceive method is called, get the users location.

3) Store this location in a SQL/SQF database.

Basically, I have all the code working. However, I'd prefer to do step 2 and 3 with two different plugins, as to create more modularity. But to do so, I need to have an instance of a FlutterView, such that I can do a "`MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).invokeMethod(methods, args);`" from Android.

(In android/Java, onReceive method) I have tried to get the FlutterView from the context, like so:

```
            private FlutterView viewFromAppContext(Context context) {
                Application app = (Application) context.getApplicationContext();
                if (!(app instanceof FlutterApplication)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "viewFromAppContext app not a FlutterApplication");
                    return null;
                }
                FlutterApplication flutterApp = (FlutterApplication) app;
                Activity activity = flutterApp.getCurrentActivity();
                if (activity == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "viewFromAppContext activity is null");
                    return null;
                }
                if (!(activity instanceof FlutterActivity)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "viewFromAppContext activity is not a FlutterActivity");
                    return null;
                }
                FlutterActivity flutterActivity = (FlutterActivity) activity;
                return flutterActivity.getFlutterView();
            }
```

However, when I try to do this when the app is in the background, the activity is null.
Is it possible to create a new activity and/or flutterview in this scenario (which can direct to my 'setMethodCallHandler' method in dart)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a FlutterNativeView called with the second param set to true; it is not easy to follow, slightly divergent from the linked git repo and is engineered well in excess of your needs, but [Ben Konyi has a working example of this](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124). I think you might enjoy checking out some of the ways he kept the other plugins working and the service working, if not the methodchannel impl (with *three* callback domains).